# Should I import a class injected in another class constructor?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have to create a default/blank case of an instance (for an estimate), which uses another class (client) which itself uses another class (adress). I wonder if I should import both adress and client, or if my code could be improved.

My problem is that if I want to do a blank Estimate, I end up with

```
import {Client} from '../../models/client.model';
import {Adress} from '../../models/adress.model';
// other things
this.estimate = new Estimate('', new Client('', new Adress('', '', '', ''), '', '', '', '', ''), '', '', '', '');
```

and I have to import both Client and Adress. I thought Dependency Injection was enought to have to import only Client. My Client constructor looks like this :

```
import {Adress} from './adress.model';
export class Client {
constructor(
    public adress: Adress,
    // other properties
  ) {
  }
```

I'd expect Adress to be included in the imported Client of the first code chunk. Is there any proper way to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export classe Estimate {
  constructor(
    public estimate: string,
    public client = new Client(''),
  ) {}
}

export class Client {
  constructor(
    public name: string,
    public address = new Address('')
  ) {}
}

export class Address {
  constructor(
    public name: string,
    public street = '',
    public city = '',
  ) {}
}
```

Now, you only need to call

```
estimate = new Estimate('');
```

If you have questions about the syntax or how it works, feel free to ask them.

Comment: Thanks ! So if I get it right, the problem was I was declaring an adress of type Adress instead of instantiating a new one, is that it ?
Does it allows me to feel that new instance with an existing one ?

Comment: No, the issue is that you didn't provide a default value to your address, forcing you to provide one everytime you wanted to create a new client. With my solution, the adress is set by default. And yes, you can still provide the address as you did, `new Estimate('', new Client('', new Address('', '', '')))`

Comment: Alright I understood and applied it to my project, thanks again. 
Does this practice has a name associated to it ? Or some doc maybe ?

Comment: @Jaune it's juste a shorthand syntax : you can find information [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties), for the default/optional values it will be [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

You can use model like this:

```
export class AdressModel {
    public city: string;
    public street: string;
    public flat: string;
    public zip: string;

    constructor(obj?: Partial<AdressModel>) {
        this.city = obj && obj.city || '';
        this.street = obj && obj.street || '';
        this.flat = obj && obj.flat || '';
        this.zip = obj && obj.zip || '';
    }
}
```